# Orchard CMS: Using the Current Theme in Custom view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a controller

```
public class JobSearchResultController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View();
    }
}
```

the View   ~/Views/JobSearchResult/Index

```
@Html.Raw("<b> TEST VIEW </b>")
```

And then I register the route

```
    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] {
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "JobSearchResult",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Module.Test"},
                        {"controller", "JobSearchResult"},
                        {"action", "Index"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Module.Test"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };
    }
```

And I'm calling it in one of the other views

```
      @Html.ActionLink("Click Me", 
             "Index", 
             new { controller = "JobSearchResult", area = "Module.Test"" })
```

Works good, it takes me to the Actual View/Index displaying the plain page with

**TEST VIEW**

in localhost/Orchard.Web/JobSearchResult URL

Now, my problem is I'm expecting this page to use the current theme / current layout (masterpage) just like a normal content type

How can I do this?

I know theres an [Admin] attribute where you can be able to display in Admin view using the Admin theme but how about if I want to display it in the Client. Is there something like

```
[Client] //display in Client
public class JobSearchResultController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {

    return View();
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can apply the Orchard.Themes.ThemedAttribute:

```
[Themed] //display in Client
public class JobSearchResultController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```